# using scrapy get links recursively on multipage

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using following code I found online to recursively scrape links on multi pages. It's supposed to return me all the links I need on all pages recursively. But I ended up with only getting 100 links at maximum. Any advice will be helpful.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/jjj?is_parttime=1"]   

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()           
            items.append(item)     
        return(items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just eliminate `allow=("index\d00\.html", )` to let it parse the `next` link:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)),           
              callback="parse_items", follow= True),)
```